# MYSQL:: Stored Procedure where condition is not working

Tags: mysql, json, stored-procedures, mysql-json

i am trying to build json object from MYSQL select and pass it to out param.
everything is working fine, but my where condition is not applying when i am using json_object, json_arrayagg, json_objectagg.

my select query is,

```
SELECT   json_object('arraylist',json_arrayagg(json_object('id',id,'code', code, ..., ..., ...))) AS jsonobj
FROM     normal_table a 
WHERE    a.code='826' 
AND      a.status='true' 
AND      a.vb_code ='124' 
ORDER BY a.date_ts DESC limit 3;
```

for this query all the records from table is getting populated.

if i remove like below

```
SELECT   json_object('id',id,'code', code, ..., ..., ...) AS jsonobj 
FROM     normal_table a 
WHERE    a.code='826' 
AND      a.status='true' 
AND      a.vb_code ='124' 
ORDER BY a.date_ts DESC limit 3;
```

it returns only 3 rows as expected.

what am i doing wrong here....

Comment: You have "limit 3"...it will always return a max of 3 rows.  What is your expectation?

Comment: @Ci-CiMillsThomson, that is what i expecting, but it is returning all the rows from the table.

Comment: You have no `GROUP BY`, so this only returns 1 row that aggregates all the rows that match the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: `LIMIT` applies to the result after aggregating, not the number of rows that are aggregated.

Comment: Where is the stored procedure? This is just an ordinary query, it works the same in a SP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to limit the number of rows that are aggregated, you need to use a subquery to limit the rows that are selected, then aggregate in the main query.

```
SELECT json_object('arraylist',json_arrayagg(json_object('id',id,'code', code, ..., ..., ...))) AS jsonobj
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM     normal_table a 
    WHERE    a.code='826' 
    AND      a.status='true' 
    AND      a.vb_code ='124' 
    ORDER BY a.date_ts
    DESC limit 3
) AS x;
```